# Managed disk restore

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am new with Azure implementation, with Azure-CLI and I have a doubt.

Currently, I want to restore the managed disks of a VM that is hosted on a Recovery Services. But I have some doubts.

The Storage account is hosted in the same resource group as the Recovery Services, since Azure-CLI suggests it, is this the right way to perform the exercise?
I defined a target resource group, but this resource group should have only the VM I want to assign the disks to or should it have something else?

I am only waiting for the prerequisites, as I am concerned about the Storage Account issue, since it must be present in the same resource group as the Recovery Services. I hope you can help me,

Answer (score 0):

Created virtual machine with backup and disk like below:

[image]

> ***Note*** that: To restore the managed disks of a VM that is hosted on a Recovery Services vault, you do not need to create a new storage account. The managed disks are stored in Azure Storage and are managed by Azure. When you restore the managed disks, you will be restoring them to the same storage account that was used by the original VM.

When I tried to restore the managed disk, disk restore in storage account successfully like below:

```
az backup restore restore-disks --resource-group myResourceGroup --vault-name myRecoveryServicesVault --container-name myVM --item-name myVM --storage-account mystorageaccount --rp-name myRecoveryPointName --target-resource-group targetRG
```

[image]
[image]

You can create a new resource group to store the restored VM and its disks.

***References***:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-restore-disk#managed-disk-restore